# property name does not exist on type file typescript error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

I am using React for client side and NodeJs for backend.

I sent an image from my react application using axios post to my NodeJs server.
I get my file using const file = req.files.file

however - file should have property called "name" and also property called "data".

but when I try to access it typescript say:

property name does not exist on type File.

but I can see that this property does exist and I can read it (using @ts-ignore) with no problem and get the file name and the data, so for sure I did not typed the file correctly...

I tried typing it as File and also as Express.Multer.File
(file: File / file: Express.Multer.File)

but both dont have name and data typed and i still get this typescript error..

anybody knows what type should I give to it ?

my ts.config.json is:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "node_modules/*"
      ]
    },
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

[screenshot of code + typescript error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4j6D.png)

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I added an image with this part of code + the ts error that it shows.
please notice I managed to make it good with file.name (I added "dom" to ts config)

yet it still does not recognize file.mimetype and file.data